# Will a guest network double my WiFi bandwidth?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-transfer

I have a 802.11g router, and I have a data transfer rate of 54mbps, which is the maximum supported by that protocol. If I create a guest network on the same router, will both networks get 54mbps, or will their total be 54mbps?

Edit: I understand the 54mpbs limit to be across all devices connected to the router (e.g., if three laptops use the router, the sum of their bandwidths would not exceed 54mbps). So if I have a guest network, I can put some devices on it, freeing bandwidth on the other network.

FYI: I have already confirmed that WiFi is the bottleneck in my home network, not my ISP. We have come a long way since the 14.4 baud modem.

Comment: What model is your router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your devices can only connect to one WiFi network at a time per device. Since your router is limited to 54mbps(theoretically) max by the 802.11g then any device you connect to your router using that protocol will be limited to that transfer speed. That is not the speed of your internet, but how fast information can flow from your device to your router. It will depend on what speeds your ISP provides you.

Basically, the max speed of the connection between the router and your device will be at most 54mbps(theoretically, real world is about 10-29mbps), but depending on your ISP service it will be shared by all the networks on the router.

EDIT: I believe that the 54mbps it is not shared by all connected devices, but each individual connection would have its own '54mbps channel'. A guest network would likely slow your network. If you are looking for faster speeds and a router with a more current 802.11 protocol isn't available, wired would be the best option.

If this is confusing or you need clarification please let me know! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

#1 Get a modern router. [Here's a router](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RT-AX55/wheretobuy/) that on it's slowest bands is x10 faster than your G router. On it's higher frequency bands, it's x20 faster.

#2 G-wireless is a single band transmission. Think of a single one-way street from San Antonio to Dallas. Only one direction of traffic can travel at a time. That is Single band G wireless. So in modern terms 54mb's TX and RX doesn't happen simultaneously. The network takes turns TX'ing then RX'ing.

#3 In reality, if you want to copy+paste a picture on your Win10 from your PC to your NAS, remember SMB or NFS are TCS network connections, which mean that every packet of data has to have a verification process of, SYN-ACK-SYN. So each communicating host has to talk back and forth one at a time. Here's a conversation I just made up of how TCS communications happen over a network of a Win10 talking to a NAS when copy+pasting a picture using SMB or NFS:
TX:Win10:Gateway: broadcast to network, "Where is IP 192.168.1.45"

RX:Router:Win10: "Oh, hi Win10. I see you want to talk to 192.168.1.45. I'll route you to it."

TX:Win10:Router: "Thanks"

RX:NAS:Win10: "I see you, Win10, It looks like you want to send a 25mb picture to me."

TX:Win10:NAS "Yes, here is the first packet of the 25mb picture. It's only 1mb of it, but the rest is coming soon"

RX:NAS:Win10 "Thanks for the first 1mb packet of your 25mb picture"

TX:Win10:NAS "I'm, glad you received the first 1mb packet of the 25mb picture, I want to send you a second packet. Are you rdy to recieve it?

RX:NAS:Win10 "I see you want to send me a second 1mb packet of your 25mb picture. Yes I can recieve it."

TX:Win10:NAS: "Here comes the second packet of the 25mb picture, let me know if you recieved it."

RX:NAS:Win10:"I have recieved the second 1mb packet of your 25mb picture."

TX:Win10:NAS "I'm glad you recieved it, Are you rdy for a third?"

RX

TX

RX

etc...etc...etc...all the way to the end of the session at that point the Win10 will
close the session.

This is actually the simplified version of it, because remember the G-wireless router has to transfer each packet between the hosts. So the router actually sets up a 1 way transfer between the Win10 and the NAS for every single packet passing through the router.
So if 54mbs on a G network feels really slow. It's because IT IS. This is a situation where there are just 2 devices on your router. If you had more than 3 devices with mapped network drives, your are talking about super slow speeds as your G router has to keep up with each of your laptops and PC's on the network to talk to your NAS. You can effectively x20 your speeds just by getting a modern A/C or a very new protocol AX router.